# Git failed to push refs to git@heroku

Tags: git, heroku, github

i've searched the boards and tried to figure out the answer to my problem--i've tried lots of different things including "git mergetools," "git pull," to try to merge the conflicts, but i'm not quite sure what is going on. there are two other collaborators on the code.

couldn't figure it out using the available world wide web, so i made duplicate files of the files i wanted to change, deleted the folder and recloned the repo directly from git so that what i see on my local is the same as what's currently on github. now that i think about it, that's probably not where the problem lives, because i was able to `git commit -am ""` without any issues.

this is what i keep seeing in my command terminal though--when i run `git pull` it says that everything is up to date.

```
`$ git pull origin master
xxxxxxxxxxx
* branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
$ git push origin master
Counting objects: 13, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5/5), 455 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 5 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
To git@github.com:
668af9c..b88dbf4  master -> master
$ git push heroku master
Fetching repository, done.
To git@heroku.com:pareup.git
! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:pareup.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
$ git pull
Already up-to-date.`
```

---

Comment: Are you on your local branch master? what does git status say?

Comment: git status says on branch master--

Comment: was able to duplicate error i was seeing with `git pull heroku master` trying to merge the conflicts now--how do i commit the merge?

Comment: As normal, fix the conflicts then git commit -am 'fixed conflicts' then push again

Comment: thank you so much! that was a stupid question--but prior to that i'd been following another online tutorial that for some reason said to just type in `git commit -a` and then git started "recording" for 10 minutes and i couldn't return to the command line. it worked!